# Typescript React - use MouseEvents without passing it to child element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mouseevent, react-typescript, onhover

Can I use Mouse Events on whole React Element or I have to pass it to child element to get it work? After several functions components where I passed my handleEvent function I want to know if it's possible without getting a TypeScript error. My code is really simple

```
<Tile onHover={handleHover} name="Random name"/>
```

and Tile component

```
export const Tile: React.FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <div className="tile-wrapper">
            <h1 className="tile-header>
                {name}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to combine `React.DOMAttributes<HTMLElement>` with your custom props using an intersection. That will avail all the DOM events to your custom component, without having to manually pass it in.

```
export const Tile: React.FC<{ name: string } & React.DOMAttributes<HTMLElement>> = ({ name, ...events }) => {
    return (
        <div className="tile-wrapper" {...events}>
            <h1 className="tile-header>
                {name}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `Title` component does not expect an `onHover` prop, it will just be ignored. The event you want to use is rather `onMouseOver`, which works on most HTML elements ([according to documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)):

> All HTML elements, EXCEPT: `<base>`, `<bdo>`, `<br>`, `<head>`, `<html>`, `<iframe>`, `<meta>`, `<param>`, `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<title>`

What you could do is the following, in the `Title` component:

```
export const Tile: React.FC<{ name: string, onHover: SomeType }> = ({ name, onHover }) => {
    return (
        <div className="tile-wrapper" onMouseOver={onHover}>
            <h1 className="tile-header>
                {name}
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: but it's not what I want to achieve... I want to NOT pass onHover prop and make typescript not display an error there

Comment: You cannot have a prop on a component without specifying it on its props types when using TypeScript.